# cannot insert background image in table in html

Tags: html

this code works:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body  background ="images.png">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see the repeated image. but following doesn't.I see no image.

```
<html>
<head >
</head>
<body>
  <table background ="images.png">
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please use a code block when pasting a piece of code in your question / comment

Comment: Also please use CSS for describing the presentation of an HTML document.

Comment: Why is there no edit button for this?

Comment: your username is very suitable!

Answer (score 1):

Because `background` is not a valid attribute for a `table` tag. Try using CSS.

Comment: Could he put the table in a div and give that div a background! I am pretty sure it is possible to assign a table a background but he would need ALL of his users to use the same browser (and that being an old netscape one lol) I think.